Introduction to lattice gauge theory for non-high energy physicsts
Can anyone recommend a good introduction to lattice gauge theory (e.g. books, review articles, or lecture notes) that is aimed at/accessible to someone with a background in condensed matter physics, quantum information, or quantum many-body physics?  That is, an approach that doesn't start from high energy physics in the beginning, but starts with the "lattice" and builds up to "gauge theory".

The only reason to do lattice gauge theory is HEP. If you wanted to do condensed matter physics, you can just use standard QFT for condensed matter. Lattice gauge theory is meant to handle the renormalisation issues of QCD.

No, I'm not misguided.  First, LGT is applicable in cond-mat (e.g. toric code, spin liquids).  Secondly, someone might be ultimately interested in HEP, but doesn't come from a particle physics background and wants to learn some LGT, which really only requires QM and group theory.  For example, someone getting involved in quantum simulation for LGT, a major research topic these days, who is coming more from the quantum info side rather than the HEP side.

Those are not LGT... Like, I am not at all denying that they are gauge quantum theories on a lattice, but they are not LGT at all. They are condensed matter physics, which you can do as QFT or as QM, and the lattice parameter is physically there; the lattice parameter is not taken to a limit of zero at the end.
